# Group users by age for a range using Java

Tags: java

I have a 1,000,000 user list with different ages, and I want to perform a search in Java that will output just the number of people in the group based on their age range.
For example:

```
Age Group                 Age Range
1                         6 years old or younger
2                         7 to 18 years old
3                         19 to 26 years old
4                         27 to 49 years old
5                         50 to 64 years old
6                         65 to 79 years old
7                         80 years old or older
```

I want my output to display the number of people that falls within the age group if I enter a particular age group. That is:

```
If I enter 1
```

The output should be:

```
**** users found (total number of users that falls within the 
age range 6 years old or younger)
```

Any kind of data structure is perfectly OK.

This is what I've done so far:

```
 /**
 A template used to read data lines into java.util.ArrayList data structure.
 Input file: pjData.csv
 Input file must be saved under the same directory/folder as the program.
 Each line contains 5 fields, separated by commas. For example,
 959695171, 64, AZ, M, 1
 355480298, 101, TN, F, 1
 **/
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class pj3Template2
 {
  public static void main(String args[]) 
 {
String line;
String id, s, g;
Integer a, sa;
StringTokenizer st;
HealthDS2 records = new HealthDS2(); 
try   {
      FileReader f = new FileReader("pjData.csv");
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(f);
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
         st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
         id = st.nextToken(",").trim();
         a = Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken(",").trim());
         s = st.nextToken(",").trim().toUpperCase();
         g = st.nextToken(",").trim().toUpperCase();
         sa = Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken().trim());
         records.add(new HealthRec2(id, a, s, g, sa));
         } // loop until the end of file
      in.close(); 
      f.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace(); };
System.out.println(records.getSize() + " records processed.");

 // Search by age
System.out.print("Enter 1-character age abbreviation to search: ");
String ui;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ui = input.next().trim();
System.out.println("Searching all records in: " + ui);

ArrayList <HealthRec2> al = records.searchByAge(Integer.valueOf(ui.trim()));
System.out.println(al.size() + " records found.");    

     }
 }

 /**
 Data class Sample records:
 5501986, 31, WV, F, 1
 1539057187, 5, UT, M, 2
 **/
 class HealthRec2
 {
    String ID;
    Integer age;
    String state;
    String gender;
    int status;
    public HealthRec2() { }
    public HealthRec2(String i, Integer a, String s, String g, int sa)
       { ID = i; age = a;  state = s; gender = g; status = sa; }
 // Reader methods
 public String getID()     { return ID; }
 public Integer getAge()   { return age; }
 public String getState()  { return state; }
 public String getGender() { return gender; }
 public int getStatus()    { return status; }
 // Writer methods
 public void setAge(Integer a)   { age = a; }
 public void setState(String s)  { state = s; }
 public void setGender(String g) { gender = g; }
 public void setStatus(int sa)   { status = sa; }

 public String toString()
 { return ID + "  " + age + "  " + state + "   " + gender + "  " + status; }
 } // HealthRec


 // Data structure used to implement the requirement
 // This implementation uses java.util.ArrayList
 class HealthDS2
 {
 ArrayList <HealthRec2> rec;
 public HealthDS2() 
  { rec = new ArrayList <HealthRec2>(); }
 public HealthDS2(HealthRec2 r) 
 { 
 rec = new ArrayList <HealthRec2>();
 rec.add(r); 
 }
 public int getSize() { return rec.size(); }
 public void add(HealthRec2 r) { rec.add(r); }

// Search by age
// No data validation is needed -- assuming the 1-character age is valid
// Returns an ArrayList of records
public ArrayList <HealthRec2> searchByAge(Integer a)
{
ArrayList <HealthRec2> temp = new ArrayList <HealthRec2>();
  for (int k=0; k < rec.size(); ++k)
  {
  if (rec.get(k).getAge().equals(a))
     temp.add(rec.get(k));  
  }
  return temp;
  } // searchByAge
  } // HealthDS
```

My goal is to search based on `state`, `status`, `gender` and `age` group. I've done that for the others, but I'm just having a little problem with the age group since it is grouped rather than just searching for a particular age in the data file. I tried creating seven arraylists for each group but I am still having a little problem switching between groups.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I suspect one of the TreeSet.subSet methods will do what you want, if you are willing to write a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

This code does:

1. get min and max ages for the selected group
2. iterate through the ages and increments a counter for any age within the min/max
3. prints out the results

For very large datasets you'll need to use better data-structures like @kyticka mentions.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] groupMin = new int[]{0, 10, 20};
        int[] groupMax = new int[]{10, 20, 9999};

        int[] ages = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 10, 12, 76, 56, 89 };

        int targetGroup = 1;
        int count = 0;
        for( int age : ages ){
            if( age >= groupMin[targetGroup] && age < groupMax[targetGroup] ){
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Group " + targetGroup + " range is " + 
                        groupMin[targetGroup] + " - " + groupMax[targetGroup]);
        System.out.println("Count: " + count);
    }
```

You can play with it here: http://ideone.com/DAWGYX

Comment: Since the intervals do not overlap, you only need to store the maximums of each age-range. @kyticka's data-structures are not too useful; a map-of-lists would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some way to initialize your 1000000 users or even below code will generate random age for Users:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserListDemo {
    int age;
    class Users{
        int age=0;
        public Users(int a)
        {
            age=a;
        }
        public void setAge(int age)
        {
            this.age=age;
        }
        public int getAge()
        {
            return this.age;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        UserListDemo uld=new UserListDemo();
        ArrayList<Users> data=new ArrayList<Users>();
        uld.initializeUsers(data);
        System.out.println("Enter age group choice"); 
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for age group 1-6");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for age group 7-18");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for age group 19-26");
        System.out.println("Enter 4 for age group 27-49");
        System.out.println("Enter 5 for age group 50-64");
        System.out.println("Enter 6 for age group 65-79");
        System.out.println("Enter 7 for age group 80-Older");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice=sc.nextLine();
        int ch=Integer.valueOf(choice);
        long result=0;
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:
            for(Users us:data)
            {
                if(us.age<=6)
                    result++;
            }

        case 2:
            for(Users us:data)
            {
                if( us.age>=7 && us.age<=18 )
                    result++;
            }
        case 3:
            for(Users us:data)
            {
                if( us.age>=19 && us.age<=26 )
                    result++;
            }
        case 4:
            for(Users us:data)
            {
                if( us.age>=27 && us.age<=49 )
                    result++;
            }
        case 5:
            for(Users us:data)
            {
                if( us.age>=50 && us.age<=64 )
                    result++;
            }
        case 6:
            for(Users us:data)
            {
                if( us.age>=65 && us.age<=79 )
                    result++;
            }
        case 7:
            for(Users us:data)
            {
                if( us.age>=80)
                    result++;
            }


        }
        System.out.println("For the entered age group :"+ch+" ::"+result+" user has been found");


    }
    public void initializeUsers(ArrayList<Users> data)
    {
        Users us;
        Random rand=new Random();
        for(long l=0;l<1000000L;l++)
        {
            us=new Users(rand.nextInt(100));    
            data.add(us);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not especially useful - the OP already has a lot of test-cases. Code to create new ones will not fix OP's problems

Answer (score 0):

The efficient answer, with 1M records, would be to use several [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)s as indices, or even an actual database. However, since the exercise explicitly mentions ArrayLists, you are probably still learning the basics, so I will stick to those.

First, you need to be able to retrieve the group for a given person. You can do that in two ways.

- Option **A** is to add the group as a field at initialization time

  ```
  // within HealthRec2

  int group;                              // stores group number as an attribute

  private static final int[] ageGroups =  // age limits for each group
       new int[]{6, 18, 26, 49, 64, 79};

  private void updateGroup() { // <-- called from constructor and from setAge()
     int currentGroup = 0;
     for (int limit : ageGroups) {
         currentGroup ++;         // advance to next group
         if (age <= limit) break; // stop looking at limits once we reach one
     }
     group = currentGroup;
  }

  private int getGroup() { return group; }
  ```
- Option **B** is to calculate it on-the-fly for each record, instead of storing it as an attribute:

  ```
  // within HealthRec2

  private static final int[] ageGroups =  // age limits for each group
       new int[]{6, 18, 26, 49, 64, 79};

  public int getGroup() { 
     int currentGroup = 0;
     for (int limit : ageGroups) {
         currentGroup ++;         // advance to next group
         if (age <= limit) break; // stop looking at limits once we reach one
     }
     return currentGroup;
  }
  ```

With either option, you could now have very similar logic to look up people in a given age group as you have to look up records from a given state or with a given gender.

Option A is more expensive up-front, because even if you do not need the age group, you still have to calculate it and store it in an attribute, just in case. Option B is more expensive if you need to call `getGroup` several times for the same record - as option A's `getGroup` is a lot faster.

Answer (score -1):

Idea one: sort and use binary search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search

Idea two: use interval tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: OP seems to be at an early stage in learning Java; those two wikipedia links will hardly andwer OP's questions. You should explain why you think they are useful - link-only answers are discouraged. Binary search requires sorting (OP does not appear to be sorting), and for 1 pass, sorting is slower than just linear search. Interval trees are similarly overkill.